# Decrypt EAP-TLS 1.3 traffic using Wireshark

Tags: ssl, wireshark, tls1.3

I am authenticating to my radius server using EAP-TLS v1.3 protocol. As TLSv1.3 mandates, all the certificates used are Elliptic curve (`secp256-r1`). However, the SSL tab of Wireshark supports only RSA Keys for now.

I want to decrypt the traffic on my supplicant (peer). Is there a way that can be done? (In a somewhat similar manner to Master Shared Secret method used for web browsers).

Any other program that can help me analyze the traffic?

Thanks in advance and apologies if I am missing something here. I am using wpa_supplicant v2.9 on peer.

Comment: Hi Rohit! A [related question](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/51448/decrypting-dtls-with-ecc-key) answered by one of the maintainers indicates elliptic curve keys won't work (as you found). You will want to ask this question on [Wireshark's forum](https://ask.wireshark.org), as this pertains to Wireshark usage.

Comment: You need to extract the session key somehow. If one of the endpoints are under your control, you can generate session key file (https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret). Otherwise decyphering is impossible, since ECDH (Ellipti Curve Diffie Hellman) key generation scheme is absolutely secure, even if you know the key of one of the parties.

Comment: It looks like it may be possible to get the master secret with GDB because wpa_supplicant is written in C: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80158/extract-pre-master-keys-from-an-openssl-application. You would need to compile and run it from [source](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wpa_supplicant.html) to generate debugging info (flag -g).